# Test positive semi-definiteness, on the submatrices.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{(n\times n)}$ be a real square matrix, and additional let an equal number of rows and columns coincide, as
$$A_{i,j}=A_{i',j}  \quad \mbox{and}\quad A_{i,j}=A_{i,j'},$$
with $i\neq i'$ and $j\neq j'$.

Can one conclude that $A$ is positive semi-definite if and only if the smaller matrix $M$ is positive semi-definite? Where $M$ is a square submatrix of $A$ with the duplicated columns and rows deleted.

What if, additional, $A$ is a symmetric matrix $A^T=A$ ?

I am aware of the theorem: Every principal submatrix of a positive definite matrix is positive definite. But not sure if that can be used since some eigenvalues might be zero, hence positive **semi**-definite.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the theorem also holds for positive semidefinite matrices.

Comment: But even if it does, it does not answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll only deal with the symmetric case.

A symmetric matrix is positive semidefinite iff every principal minor is nonnegative.  Of course if a principal minor includes some identical rows and columns, it is $0$.  So  the symmetric matrix $A$ is positive semidefinite iff its symmetric submatrix obtained by deleting duplicate rows and columns is positive semidefinite.

EDIT:
The answer is no in the non-symmetric case.
Consider the $3 \times 3$ matrix
$$ A = \pmatrix{1 & 1 & 1\cr
            1 & 1 & 1\cr
            0 & 1 & 1\cr} $$
which has two equal rows and two equal columns.  Using the definition of positive semidefinite that allows real non-symmetric matrices, it is not positive semidefinite: note that $(A + A^T)/2$ has negative determinant.
But the submatrix
$$ M = \pmatrix{1 & 1\cr 0 & 1\cr}$$
obtained by deleting a duplicated row and column is positive definite.